# Retrieving CGVector from UserDefaults (Swift)?

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit, nsuserdefaults

How can I properly retrieve this data from user defaults?

Saving force from north player class:

```
let forceSave = UserDefaults.standard
forceSave.set(directionVector, forKey: "NorthForce")
forceSave.synchronize()
```

Retrieving force vector value from game scene in collision detection function (player collides with ball):

```
ball!.physicsBody!.applyImpulse(UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "NorthForce"))
```

I get the following error when trying to retrieve data:
"Cannot convert value of type 'Data?' to expected argument type 'CGVector'"

As a background, I was delegating this data initially, but I found that I had to retrieve the data in a separate function when I delegated it. So the force calculation was an extra frame off which makes a difference when the game is played at fast speeds. I decided to try user defaults because I could access the data directly in the collision detection function.

Comment: What is `directionVector`? If it is not a Data, then why are you retrieving it with `data(forKey:)`? On the other hand, if it is not a Data, then how do you expect to save it into UserDefaults in the first place? I suspect that it is supposed to be a CGVector. In that case you must _encode_ it into UserDefaults and _decode_ it when you retrieve it.

Comment: Thank you @matt. I resolved this by sending each field of vector individually. I retrieved them as floats.